# How do I start a sentence after a quote that did not end with a period

Tags: quotation-marks, periods

I have the following Erratum:

The Editors regret that in the original article two formulations are misleading for the reader:

1. In the original publication, the last sentence of the Introduction is: “Section 5 also indicates this.”. This sentence should be replaced by: “Section 5 also indicated this.”.
2. In the original publication, point 2 reads: “other theories contemporaneously accepted;”. This should be replaced by: “other theories accepted;”.

My questions are: in (1.), is the use of period-quotation mark-period OK? And in (2.), should I write periods immediately after the closing quotation marks?

Comment: Why are you keeping the semicolons? In MLA I’m pretty sure that you can silently drop it as it is not “interior punctuation”.

Comment: @Laurel These are indeed interior. They are part of the quotes I'm quoting. I need to keep them because I need to quote the entire text of one point within a list of points.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108626/discussion-on-question-by-philosopher-of-science-how-do-i-start-a-sentence-after).